BioPython - qblast() timeout every time, running from python shell
I am a new user to BioPython. I have set up my virtual env and installed BioPython via pip inside the venv.
I am following the instructions in the BioPython cookbook/tutorial here.
First, I import the module:
>>>from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
Then I set my email, using: >>>NCBIWWW.email=myemail@domain.com, as the guidelines specify.
Finally, I run the query:
>>> result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", "8332116")
Every time I try to send this query, it hangs a really long time. Eventually I get the following warning:
/home/user/python/covid_dna/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Bio/Blast/NCBIWWW.py:281: BiopythonWarning: BLAST request BHFD53MJ016 is taking longer than 10 minutes, consider re-issuing it
  warnings.warn(

I expected the query to return a result to result_handle.
Instead, either the query fails, or I send keyboard interrupt with ctrl+c as it has hung for over 30 minutes.
Am I using incorrect syntax? Have I failed to set some variable, such as the url_base correctly?
I have run the same BLAST query using the web interface, which returns an expected BLAST search result:
web_blast_result

Posting just in case anyone was actually reading this. It turned out to be a DNS or other network connectivity issue, perhaps on the NCBI server side. I ran the same query a few days later and it behaved as expected.
